# How could I get the text after the line break? Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to get the text after the line break to the end point, as in the following example:

```
PRODUCT:
Product detail.
```

I can do it as long as there is not a line break but I do not know how to do it if the line break is included. This is my code:

```
const product = 'PRODUCT:';
let resultProduct = text.match(new RegExp(product + '\\s(\\w+)', 'i'))[1];
```

Comment: What is expected output ?

Comment: `\s` will match a line break, so I don't know why the line break is an issue here.

Comment: What about trying something like this -> var left_text = input_string.substring(input_string.indexOf("\n")+1);? Check here https://jsfiddle.net/gzqu4fy9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `\s` to match space character, match the newline character `\n`.

You can `.split()`  `product` and the newline character `\n` and `.pop()` the resulting array to get the last element. Or use bracket notation to get element at index `1` `[1]` to get second element in array

```js
const text = `PRODUCT:
Product detail.`;

const product = 'PRODUCT:';

let resultProduct = text.split(new RegExp(`${product}\\n`))[1];

console.log(resultProduct);
```

Alternatively you can match `product`, newline character and new line or next line to the end, then get the element at index `0` of the resulting array

```js
const text = `PRODUCT:
Product detail.`;

const product = "PRODUCT";
    
let resultProduct = text.match(new RegExp(`${product}\\n|.+$`, 'g'))[0];

console.log(resultProduct);
```

Comment: Thaks, Your code works (let resultProduct = text.match(new RegExp(`${product}\\n|.+$`, 'g')).pop();) but it throws me a text that does not match the one that goes under Product: it takes the last string of text and that's what it shows. Would you know how to get it to take the text under Product: ??

Comment: @OscarDev You can get the value at index `0` of the resulting array `let resultProduct = text.match(new RegExp(${product}\\n|.+$, 'g'))[0]`. See updated post.

Comment: Thank you. that same thing I tried since I understand that pop takes the last element of the array and returns it so I better ask for the element in step [0] but anyway it returns the last element of the text   :/

Comment: @OscarDev By _"it returns the last element of the text :/ "_ do you mean the expected result?

Comment: What happens is that the text is something like:
Product:
Description ...
Model:
Desciption ...
Schedule:
Description...

So I need only the one under "product:" but the last one in this case is the one in the schedule.

Comment: @OscarDev Given the example string and same line breaks as described in the question you can substitute `[^\\n]` for `$` at the `RegExp` `text.match(new RegExp(\`${product}\\n|.+[^\\n]\`, 'ig'))[1]` to match `Description ...` at the next line following `Product:` case insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

If the character between the lines is a simple new line character (\n), then you should be able to use:

```
let resultProduct = text.match(new RegExp(product + '\\n(.*$)','i'))[1]
```

Otherwise, if there is a combination of line feeds (\r) and carriage returns (\n) between the lines, then the following can handle that situation better:

```
let resultProduct = text.match(new RegExp(product + '(?:\\n|\\r)+(.*$)','i'))[1]
```

Comment: `[\n\r]` is simpler than `(?:\n|\r)`.

Answer (score 0):

What about trying something like this ?
 `var left_text = input_string.substring(input_string.indexOf("\n")+1);`
 Check here:
https://jsfiddle.net/gzqu4fy9/